# How to import constants from TypeScript files dinamically?

Tags: typescript, import, async-await

I want to import constants from external TypeScript files into a field of class like this:

**src/app/i18n/en/my-class.lang.ts**

```js
export name = 'Name';
export email = 'E-mail';
```

**my-class.model.ts**

```js
export class MyClass {
  lang = 'en';

  fields = {
    ...await import('src/app/i18n/'+ lang + '/my-class.lang'),
    ...await import('src/app/i18n/'+ lang + '/general.lang'),
  };
}
```

Now I get `'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.` error message.

Is there any best practice to do this import?

Comment: Why are you trying to import them in a property initializer? Import them and then assign them to the class property

Comment: Because I don't want to import all of the languages files to save resources... imagine that situation there is more than 20 languages and lang files size over 100kB/language.

Comment: I want to load only that language what the user use and if the user change language then load the actual one only.

Comment: Since dynamic imports are asynchronous, you won't be able to do it in a field initializer. Thus, you probably won't want to do it in a model style class but in some sort of application service.